# How to Disable Browser Back Button functionality after click on Logout Button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I am having trouble with the browser back button.
When the User press Log out it have to destroy the session and cookies. I wrote the following code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function disablebackbutton(){
            window.history.forward();
        }
        disablebackbutton();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="<?php echo __PROJECT_LINK__; ?>/php/login_exec.php">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                <?php
                                if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR']) >0 ) {
                                    echo '<ul class="err">';
                                    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] as $msg) {
                                        echo '<span class="label label-warning" style="margin-left: 5px;">',$msg,'</span>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</ul>';
                                    unset($_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR']);
                                }
                                ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subnav subnav-fixed nav navbar" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                    <span class="label label-default" style="margin-left: 22px;">Username</span>
                                    <input type="text" id="inputUserName" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                                </li>
                                <li style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                    <span class="label label-default" style="margin-left: 22px;">Password</span>
                                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                                </li>
                                <li style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!--?php $this->btnLogLogin->Render();?-->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login_exec.php**

```
<?php
    //Start session
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
     if(isset($_POST['username']))
     {
    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag==true) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:../index.php");
    exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_name='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($row['User_Status']=="Active"){
                $expire=time()+60*60*24*30; //1month
                setcookie("User_id", $row['User_id'], $expire);
                $name = $row['full_name'];
                $parts = explode(" ", $name);
                $lastname = array_pop($parts);
                $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);
                $_SESSION['USER']  = $firstname;
                $_SESSION['UID']  = $row['User_id'];
                $_SESSION['URights'] = $row['Rights'];
                header("location:../welcome.php");
            }
            else{
                $errmsg_arr[] = 'User Status is Block. Please contact your Administrator.';
                $errflag = true;
                if($errflag) {
                    $_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                    session_write_close();
                    header("location: ../index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    //Login failed
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password not found';
    $errflag = true;
    if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: ../index.php");
    exit();
    }
    }
    }else {
    die("Query failed");
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<?php include 'qcubed.inc.php'; ?>
<?php
    $User_Name = $_SESSION['USER'];
    ?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Welcome <?php echo $User_Name; ?></h1>
      <h2><a href = "<?php echo __PROJECT_LINK__; ?>/Info.php">Info</a></h2> 
      <h2><a href = "<?php echo __PROJECT_LINK__; ?>/php/logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**Info.php**

```
    <?php include '../../qcubed.inc.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?php echo __PROJECT_TITLE__; ?> - Full Info</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function disablebackbutton(){
                window.history.forward();
            }
            disablebackbutton();
        </script>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['UID']) && $_SESSION['UID'] != "")
{
//Task to do
        $User_Name = $_SESSION['USER'];
?>
<body>
         <h1>Info about <?php echo $User_Name; ?></h1> 
          <h2><a href = "<?php echo __PROJECT_LINK__; ?>/php/logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
       </body>
<?php
}
else{
    //redirect URL
    ?>
       <script>
            alert('You must Login first.');
            window.location.href='../../index.php';
        </script>";
   <?php

    exit();
}
?>

     </html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
//session_write_close();
    session_start(); # NOTE THE SESSION START
    $expire=time()-60*60*24*30; //1month
    if(isset($_COOKIE['User_id'])):
        setcookie('User_id', '', $expire, '/');
    endif;
    unset($_SESSION['UID']);
    unset($_SESSION['USER']);
    unset($_SESSION['URights']);
    unset($_SESSION['UReg']);
    $_SESSION = array();
    foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../index.php");
    exit(); # NOTE THE EXIT
?>
```

After pressing log out from Info.php , when I press the browser back button it is showing my previous Logined user page and session username in Info.php page,
but if I use the following javascript in head section of every page it disable all the browser back button at the time of login also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disablebackbutton(){
            window.history.forward();
        }
        disablebackbutton();
    </script>
```

I want to disable the browser back button only after the the time of logout.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than disabling the back button, you can add code to every page to see if the user is logged.  If they are NOT logged in, redirect to the login page.

You could create a basic class to handle this for you and just create one on every page.

```
class sessionHandler
{

    function __construct($special = NULL)
    {

        session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // 1 year
        session_start();

        // if no user num (empty session) AND this isn't the login page
        if (!isset($_SESSION['userID']) && $special != 'LOGIN') {
            //send to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        }

        if ($special == 'LOGOUT') {
            // This is the logout page, clear the session and
            // send the user to the afterLogout page

            session_destroy();   // clear session files on server
            $_SESSION = Array(); // clear session variable for this session
            unset($_SESSION);

            // send to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        }

        if ($special == 'LOGIN') {
            // This is the login page, see if user is already logged in
            // if so, just send them to the afterLogin page
            // if not, validate their credentials, and store the USERID
            // in the $_SESSION var

            if ($this->getUserPermissions($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                 // send to any page you want
                 header("location: dashboard.php");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now, on all your pages, put `$session = new sessionHandler();` at the top (before anything else is written.

For login and logout pages you'd put:
`$session = new sessionHandler('LOGIN');`
`$session = new sessionHandler('LOGOUT');`

Not copy and paste ready, but hopefully that points you in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That became my problem before. On my case i did not disable the back button. what i did is to check the session when the user is logged out. if there has no detected session, redirect the user to log in page or to what page you like the to redirect.. if there is a detected session redirect it to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS CODE in  login_exec.php**

```
 if($errflag==true) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location:../index.php");
        exit();
        }

        //Create query
        $qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_name='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if($row['User_Status']=="Active"){
                    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30; //1month
                    setcookie("User_id", $row['User_id'], $expire);
                    $name = $row['full_name'];
                    $parts = explode(" ", $name);
                    $lastname = array_pop($parts);
                    $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);
                    $_SESSION['USER']  = $firstname;
                    $_SESSION['UID']  = $row['User_id'];
                    $_SESSION['login']=true; //ADD THIS CODE IN login_exec.php
                    $_SESSION['URights'] = $row['Rights'];
                    header("location:../welcome.php");
                }
                else{
                    $errmsg_arr[] = 'User Status is Block. Please contact your Administrator.';
                    $errflag = true;
                    if($errflag) {
                        $_SESSION['ERRMsg_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                        session_write_close();
                        header("location: ../index.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**now add the code top of the info.php**

```
    session_start();
    $user=$_SESSION['USER'];
    if($_session['login']=true && $_session['user']= $user)
    {

    code of info.php 
    }
else
{

header(location:index.php);
}
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['USER']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: yeah, I used that one but after that logout it is going back again. if I not use 
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disablebackbutton(){
            window.history.forward();
        }
        disablebackbutton();
    </script>

Comment: I use this code on my site, and when I click logout the page redirects and destroys session, which is fine.However when I click the back button I can still view the page. If I refresh it, then it will redirect me to login as the session has been destroyed and the user does not have access to the page like expected.
I just want to know sir is there a way I can prevent the user from being able to view the page when they click the back button? Please help me sir... Thank you for your valuable response ..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition at all the pages which user can access only if he is login:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['UID']) || $_SESSION['UID'] == ''){
    // redirect to index or login page
}
```

Comment: Back button is not disable by this but user can't access your pages after logout.

Answer (score 0):

At last I solved my problem ..... :-)
I use this following code in

**logout.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    window.history.forward();
    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(1); }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>

</head>
<body onload="preventBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) preventBack();" onunload="">
Please Wait..
<?php

session_start(); # NOTE THE SESSION START
$expire=time()-60*60*24*30; //1month
if(isset($_COOKIE['User_id'])){
    setcookie('User_id', '', $expire);
}
unset($_SESSION['UID']);
unset($_SESSION['USER']);
unset($_SESSION['URights']);
unset($_SESSION['UReg']);
$_SESSION = array();
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("Refresh: 2;url=../index.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it's avoid me to use browser back button after logout and destroy the session.
Thank you all for yours valuable support...